# Stuttering with WD TV Live connected to iMac via ethernet?

Tags: mac, streaming, ethernet, imac, wdtv

I have a WD TV Live, if I connect a hard drive or usb stick to the usb input on it, it plays all my movies flawlessly. However if I connect the WD TV to my iMac directly via ethernet (no router), all my movies stutter considerably and are unwatchable. These are not big files either, 700mb 2 hour avi's. I borrowed a friends DWA-160 wireless usb stick (this time going through my router) and have the same issue, everything stutters like crazy and is unwatchable. I stream movies from my iMac to my Macbook Air all the time without any issue. So it seems the WD TV Live is the problem, I've updated the firmware.. I don't understand what the issue is, no one else seems to have issues with stuttering unless they run out of bandwidth because they're streaming 20 gig files. I can't even stream over ethernet.. help!

Comment: I think that the problem lies in the Samba protocol. You may try again to watch the videos via a media player app like Playback